# Download certificate using openssl and setting certificate to libCURL

Tags: c++, c, openssl, libcurl

I have written an application to download the server certificate using openssl. Then I used this certificate in libCURL to communicate to HTTPS communication. LibCRL gives invalid certificate error (60).

After searching in libCURL site they said to use ‘cacert.pem’ file. Then I set the option CURLOPT_CAINFO  to ‘cacert.pem’ and  ‘CURLOPT_CAPATH’ to downloaded certificate file. Then it worked fine.

Then I came to know that the root certificate is missing in the downloaded certificate and that root certificate is present in ‘cacert.pem’ file.

Now my query is

1) How to download root certificate from server?

2) Also please let me know best practice to set the certificates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Never** download a root certificate from the server. The whole point of the infrastructure is that you already have a set of *trusted* root certificates. If someone signed (directly or indirectly) with this root certificate, then you can trust the certificate. If you download the root certificate from the server you are basically dropping the whole idea of certificates and could as well use HTTP.

There is an alternative, however, if you are working with your own certificates (self-signed): You can either [maintain your own CA](http://www.g-loaded.eu/2005/11/10/be-your-own-ca/) and create a special `cacert.pem` for this purpose or you disable certificate checking (the latter is not recommended as it makes your application less secure!).

If you are doing some advanced stuff, i.e. not having a certificate signed by a CA included in standard bundles like libCURL's `cacert.pem` then you should definitely read up on the theory behind this, because otherwise you are risking to create a vulnerable application right from the start.